# App Binaries: files submitted

Tags: ios, xcode, binaries, mobileprovision

I have just been introduced to a code bank of an iphone app that has been submitted to the app store several times. The most recent version was submitted in spring 2011.

I can find the zip files of all the iOS app binaries submitted. However, when I try to download the zip, there are two files: .mobileProvision (of kind "Developer Provisioning Profile"), and the "application" (the "kind" says "application", so thats what I'm inferring).

XCode will not open the .mobileProvision file. Also, Finder gives me the message, "you can’t open the application because it is not supported on this type of Mac."

My questions are:

1. what is a .mobileProvision file?
2. Is there a way for me to hack it open in xcode?
3. What do app binaries include? Just the changes from the previous version? Or all the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long and the short of it is:

These files were used as part of the application submission process. They do not have any other use -- they're essentially junk at this point.

You will need to find the source code of your application to continue working with it. (These files do not contain the source code, so they're no good to you.)